# Gap in firefox's File Menu

Tags: firefox

Firefox's menu has some gap between options. Is this a bug in my ubuntu version of firefox or in the browser itself? Is anyone else facing the issue? How to fix this?

[image: Firefox16 menu]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which version of Firefox?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04. Latest firefox from software-center, Firefox16

Answer (score 0):

Did you try restarting firefox or rebooting your computer :P If you had already tried the obvious ways, then follow this.

Check in Private Browsing mode by typing (Ctrl+Shift+p). If you didn't see the issue in that mode, it may be due to some addons. Disabling addons might help.

If issue still persists, then uninstall firefox and install it again

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove firefox
sudo apt-get install firefox
```